# Converting date string to Datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime

I have a function which returns in YYYY-MM-DD i want to add 10 days to this date and check if today is the date. how can i do that.

```
def date_return:
    return YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: That's not valid Python in the least...

Comment: you can use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for convert string to datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`datetime.date.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) to turn YYYY-MM-DD into a `datetime.date`.
2. Use `datetime.timedelta(days=10)` to add 10 days to that date.
3. Compare it to `datetime.date.today()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> yyyymmdd = "2022-09-04"
>>> print(
...   datetime.date.fromisoformat(yyyymmdd) + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
...   == datetime.date.today()
... )
True
```